# Can't figure out where to install yarn add dropzone for my rails app on Digitalocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, dropzone

I want to install `yarn add dropzone` on my Digital Ocean droplet for my Rails application.
It works fine in my dev envirment... I have tried to upload into my server's root folder, then the app root like you would in dev, then I installed in the current directory which I figured it went...

```
@myskiswap-test:~/myskiswap/current$ ls
Capfile     Gemfile.lock  Procfile.dev  Rakefile      assets_manifest_backup  config     docker  node_modules  postcss.config.js  test    yarn.lock
Dockerfile  Guardfile     README.md     Testing.html  babel.config.js         config.ru  lib     ok            public             tmp
Gemfile     Procfile      REVISION      app           bin                     db         log     package.json  storage            vendor
```